# Two-line text in SPAN taking 100% of width in both lines

Tags: html, css

So guys, I'm trying to create a fancy description in my webpage and I want the first words of each paragraph to be the title of that paragraph. But I also want to the rest of the text to come right after the end of the title. I want to achieve something like this:

> **A Single Line Title** more text come here
>   and here and here and here and here........
>   ....
>
> **A Two Line Title Will Eventually Happen And This is Really looooooooooooooooooooooong and I need this behavior** more text come 
>   here and here and here and here and here...
>   ....

I'm wrapping the title (that will have different style) in a SPAN element. Everything goes well when it comes to a short title. But when I need it to have 2 lines, the second line does not wrap the content and stretch to 100% of the width, because it is the first line width.

I'm using only one SPAN element per title. And everything is inside a P element. Have a look in this piece of code

HTML

```
 <div class='column'>
        <p><span class='title'>Short title comes here</span>  text ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...</p>
        <p><span class='title'>A longer title come here and goes on and on and on and on and on</span> text ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... </p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.column p .title{
font-weight: bold;
display: inline;
font-size: 15pt;
color: rgb(0,0,0);
line-height: 14pt;
margin-right: 5px;}
```

And also I uploaded this image to make things clearer

https://docs.google.com/a/uniriotec.br/file/d/0B2abPynX9PhkYzRydGJQT2JlbHM/edit?usp=drive_web

Do you guys have any good idea how to solve this problem? Is there a way to use only one SPAN to represent the title?

@EDIT
You are right, my friends. I actually was very confused with the output of my code. But after reading your answers I decided to inspect that elements more carefully. So I noticed that the 'title' element has a `float: left` CSS rule that was resulting in this malfunction. So I added `float: none` to `.title` and everything works fine now. Thank you all!

Comment: `p` is `block-level` element, and you have an `inline` element (span) inside it.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're doing, but it seems to work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/joelworsham/LEbam/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want your titles to behave like a block element before them, however to remain inline after them.

### Solution #1

Wrap the title spans within some wrapper which is floated left and cleared.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/t5rAN/3/)**

### Markup

```
 <div class='column'>
     <span class="wpr"><span class='title'>Short title comes here</span>  text ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...</span>
     <span class="wpr"><span class='title'>A longer title come here and goes on and on and on and on and on</span> text ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.title
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.wpr
{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

---

### Solution #2

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/t5rAN/1/)**

### Markup

```
 <div class='column'>
     <span class='title'>Short title comes here</span>  text ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
     <span class='title'>A longer title come here and goes on and on and on and on and on</span> text ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
</div>
```

### CSS

```
span
{
    font-weight: bold;
    inline-block;
}
span:before 
{ 
    content:"\A"; white-space:pre; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the p element is a block level element so it will take up the whole row, if you want that changed you would need to add an identifier to the the `<p></p>` target you want the 50% width and set it to display inline here is a jsfiddle is this what you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/fmG6D/

Edit you could also use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I would change that to `display:inline-block` rather than just `inline` - http://jsfiddle.net/fmG6D/2/ :)

Comment: Yeah you could do that as well + you can then set some margins or padding for top or bottom of element